# OSX Applescript/Automator action to trim + untrim videos in iPhoto

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

Can Applescript or Automator do specific repeatable steps within OS X apps, specifically iPhoto? If so, i'd love to see some examples!

I want to do the "fix" described in the link below on hundreds of video files in an iPhoto library: [how-to-trim-and-share-video-in-iphoto-tutorial](http://www.icreatemagazine.com/tips/how-to-trim-and-share-video-in-iphoto-tutorial/)

In a nutshell, to get around a problem where iPhoto video thumbnails show up as black (and the built in "rebuild thumbnails" command fails) one can do the following steps to force iPhoto to regenerate a new "correct" (not black) thumbnail:

```
1) Open Video
2) Video Options (little gear icon) -> Trim
3) Trim left .1 second (this forces iPhoto to regen a thumbnail)
4) Video Options -> Reset Trim
```

These steps solve the problem but are very time consuming, so if there's a way to automate the steps above, i would be forever grateful to know how!

Comment: What format are the videos in? And what extension do they have?

Comment: @MarkSetchell .mov files all shot on iPhones.

Comment: I just looked at what hooks iPhoto exposes to Applescript and i don't see anything that would allow me to adjust trim values, so this may be a dead end. Hopefully Apple's new Photos app will resolve this issue.

Comment: How about running a little `bash` script that uses `ffmpeg` to trim the first 0.1 seconds off all of your videos?